# Large draggable item into small droppable container?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It works but it is a little problematic. When there are multiple small droppable areas near each other (15x15px) and I want to drop a 150x150px draggable item in a correct container, it is very difficult to get it right.

Is there a way to make the draggable item drop at a current cursor position?

I could then use cursorAt to specify the cursor to be outside the draggable item and it would be easy to "aim" it to correct droppable area.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found a way:

```
$('.drop').droppable({
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  drop: function() {
    //
  }
});
```